# SQL: Un campo con más de un valor

Tags: mysql, sql

mientras estaba creando una tabla en SQL, me he percatado de que necesito insertar en un mismo campo varios valores, e.g, una tabla que se llama Películas, y otra tabla con actores, entonces en la tabla de Películas, hay un campo que es actores.
¿Como puedo guardar todos los actores que participan en la película, con sus respectivos ids?

Comment: En realidad es dificil contestar porque no has compartido la estructura de tus tablas. Pero con un buen diseño, nunca deberías necesitar meterle varios valores en un mismo campo. En este caso, lo usual sería tener una fila por actor.

Comment: @A. Cedano: A menos que solo se piensa usar un solo actor por pelicula, probablemente habría necesidad de agregar una tercera tabla para definir la relación N..N entre las 2 tablas que mencionas. De lo contrario, habría duplicación de datos en la tabla `peliculas`.

Comment: Correcto @sstan,  serán necesarias tres tablas: `actores`,  `peliculas`  y una tercera que maneje las relaciones `actores_peliculas`.

Answer (score 4):

Para esto que planteas, existe la relación muchos a muchos(*Many to Many*).
Dicha relación se modela con una tabla intermedia, entre tus dos objetos que se relacionan mutuamente en varias ocasiones. Esto responde a la 3ra forma normal (*eliminar los datos no dependientes de la clave*)  En este caso **Una Película**, tiene **Muchos Actores** y **Un Actor**, puede estar en **Muchas Peliculas**.

### Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clave principal ID de estudiante identifica de forma exclusiva a cada estudiante de la tabla Alumnos. La clave principal ID de clase identifica de forma exclusiva cada clase de la tabla Clases. La tabla Matrículas contiene las claves externas ID de estudiante e ID de clase.

Para configurar una tabla de unión para una relación de muchos a muchos:

1. Crear una tabla denominada Matrículas. Será la tabla de unión.
2. En la tabla Matrículas, crear un campo ID de estudiante y un campo ID
   de clase.

> Por lo general, las tablas de unión contienen campos que no tienen
> sentido en otras tablas. Puede añadir campos a la tabla Matrículas,
> como un campo Fecha para mantener un registro de cuándo alguien inició
> una clase y un campo Coste para rastrear cuánto pagó un estudiante por
> realizar una clase.

3. Crear una relación entre los dos campos ID de estudiante de las
   tablas. A continuación, crear una relación entre los dos campos ID de
   clase de las tablas.

> Mediante este diseño, si un estudiante se matricula en tres clases,
> ese estudiante tendrá un registro en la tabla Alumnos y tres registros
> en la tabla Matrículas: un registro para cada clase en la que se ha
> matriculado el estudiante.

**En tu caso particular**: deberías definir una tabla intermedia, que contenga el ID de la película y el ID del Actor. Esto te permitirá listar con una simple consulta, todos los actores de una película, todas las películas de un actor, etc.

Comment: Gracias, se me había olvidado completamente la relación m-n